# How to use NDK? Starting with 'hello world' app

Tags: c++, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I would like to see a 'Hello world' program written in C/C++ but made to run on Android.

I know this is possible by using NDK and JNI calls. But not able to make it work. No guides online are helpful.

Need to know to to get started.

I am developing on Windows 7 machine and also using Eclipse for ease.

Android installation path: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows
and NDK I have extracted to: C:\Program Files\Android\android-ndk-r5

1. How do I import NDK to eclipse?
2. How to use C/C++ in Android?

If I could get help running a simple 'hello world' I can design most of my sensitive code with C++.

Comment: Did you tried the sample projects using the ndk?

Comment: @Macarse: yeah! But I just not able to figure out a way to make steps more simpler. Just to get all libraries into eclipse dev environment and make development process even faster. More-over when I follow these steps I cannot get it working. maybe I am Missing so many steps. Each google listing has different opinions/procedures.

Comment: When you always want to get the things done faster and without pain, that's a problem. You must learn first how things work and understand the basis of what you are learning, then you can worry about finding a way to make the development process faster.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are samples in the android-ndk-r5 folder + there is a nice step-by-step tutorial:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/index.html

No excuses, dude. You just have to read (take a look at the *Exploring the hello-jni Sample* section).

Comment: "No excuses, dude. You just have to read." You caught me right. Will give a look into. :-)

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Download NDK from https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html.
>   2) After this copy the location where the ndk is stored.
>   3) Open preferences from window menu (Eclipse -> Preferences on Mac OS).
>   4) Inside preferences there is Android title and click that.
>   5) Then open Ndk and paste the copied Ndk location inside the Edittext.

Now location of the Ndk is set in your eclipse and than

> 1) create new project.
>   2) Right click on the project and than select Android Tools and select Add Native.

Support

Automatic creation of jni folder in your project

Answer (score 3):

Install the SDK and NDK like this: https://askubuntu.com/a/732010/52975

Plug in your device via USB and run:

```
git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk
cd android-ndk
git checkout a5fdebebdb27ea29cb8a96e08e1ed8c796fa52db
cd hello-jni
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew installAllDebug
```

Now the app should be installed in your device.

`hello-jni` is the simplest C example, and there are also C++ examples like `Teapot`.

Those examples use Gradle, and there are Ant `Android.mk` examples under the branch [android-mk](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk). You can build those with:

```
 ndk-build
 android update project -p . -t android-23
 ant clean
 ant debug
 ant installd
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, Android 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

1.Creating project and check NDK support.

2.If NDK is not installed ,install it from Android sdk manager.

3.Install Cmack plugin.

4.Synch project

5.Run app

Upgrade Studio version above 2.2