# How to call C++ from Java?

Tags: java, c++, xml, java-native-interface

I wanted to call a C++ method from Java.  I read about JNI, but I am not getting how to get all the library files and where I should keep it in order to run the program from command line.

Is there any way to call a C++ method from Eclipse itself, because I am using it to run Java classes.

Comment: Take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212982/jni-unable-to-fix-this-error/7213943#7213943

Comment: just follow any JNI tutorial and get started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use NDK? Starting with 'hello world' app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777935/how-to-use-ndk-starting-with-hello-world-app)

Answer (score 9):

While I've used JNI-C++ bridging in the past (only a little though) - it can be a bit ugly. You might want to consider using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) to help you generate all the messy boiler plate code.

Answer (score 7):

If JNI is too complicated you can take a look at [JNA](https://web.archive.org/web/20120223211303/http://today.java.net/article/2009/11/11/simplify-native-code-access-jna). In first case you have to create native wrapper code (in C or C++) to join Java and native (C++/C/...) code. In second case it is done at runtime (so you only need Java code + config).

Comment: "JNI" is the standard answer.  But if JNA meets your needs - cool!  @Fernando Miguelez: Great suggestion!  Thank you for sharing!  Here's another link:  http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2008/jw-02-opensourcejava-jna.html

Answer (score 5):

I use JNR/FFI https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi which I have found to be faster than JNA and easier than SWIG. It's as close to JNI for speed I have found but less error prone.

Comment: BTW, JavaCPP is just as fast as JNR. I even stumbled across a performance regression in JDK 11 when running some benchmarks against Panama with it: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210975

Answer (score 4):

I have used JNA before for simple interfaces and it was simple and elegant enough. It is advised though, that if there is a complex interface then it's better to use SWIG.

There are some good answers that compare SWIG with JNI and JNA. It's a while since the question was asked though.

[SWIG vs JNI and JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720563/access-c-shared-library-from-java-jni-jna-cni-or-swig)

Answer (score 4):

JavaCPP - https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp

It provides efficient access to native C++ inside Java. Under the hood, it uses JNI, so it works with all implementations of Java SE.

Much easier than JNA/JNI

Answer (score 4):

Call c++ code from java program.

**Follow the below Step**

> 1. write java code
>
>    - that contian declaration of native methods
>    - load shared library contain native code
>    - call native method

```
public class Sample1 
{
     public native int intMethod(int n);
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          System.loadLibrary("Sample1");
          Sample1 sample = new Sample1();
          int     square = sample.intMethod(5);
          System.out.println("intMethod: " + square);
     }
}
```

> 2. Compile java code

`javac Sample2.java`

> 3. create c++ header file

`javac Sample2.java`

> 4. Write c++ code

```
#include "Sample1.h"
#include <string.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Sample1_intMethod
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint num) {
   return num * num;
}

void main(){}
```

> 5. compile c++ code

`cc -G Sample1.c -o Sample1.so`

> 6. Run java program

`java Sample1`

Answer (score 1):

**JNA** can be used instead of JNI .

All you need is to download **JNA jar**( *https://github.com/java-native-access/jna#download* ) Which should be included in your java project.

You need to give the location of your c++ library in your project properties.

- Right click project
- **Run**
- In VM options include this  **-Djava.library.path="C:Your dll
  location"**.

Visit this site for an example which also has a source code for Java and c++ project to know how this works. ( *http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/#a_downloads* )

Comment: Why not to use JNI?

Answer (score 0):

How to call a C/C++ function from Java then you can use Java Native Interface (JNI), part of the Java platform, is an interface that enables communication between Java applications running on a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and native applications or libraries written in other programming languages (e.g. C, C++). You can use some below URLs for as examples.

http://malinsky.eu/blog/how-to-call-a-c-function-from-java/
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html