# How to import a C++ library into eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am wanting to import a C++ library (folder with C++ files) into eclipse. I've been looking online and haven't had much luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call C++ from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593334/how-to-call-c-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

Please, it was the first google result:

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_existing_code.htm

Comment: I followed the tutorial (importing from file system) and after attempting to include, it states that the file was not found

Comment: what OS are you using?
Anyway, how about this:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_external_library_to_my_C.2B.2B_project.3F