# How can i create a native method and his implementation .cpp file in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, c++, intellij-idea

I need to use some c++ things in a java project, can i do it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getCpuTemp());
}

private static native int getCpuTemp();
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593334/how-to-call-c-from-java. ?

Comment: I've just done it one time in Android Studio that is at least the same of Intellij IDEA but Android Studio automatically creates the java method and the cpp file. I don't know the folder where i've to put the cpp file and then call System.loadLibrary("")

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA does not have any support for C++. You can edit .cpp files as plain text, but that's it - you won't get any additional assistance.

Comment: Where i've to place the .cpp? @yole